# sshfs: Input/Output error

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I cannot enter my sshfs, although I'm sure that the connection is fine and the destination exists. Every file operation fails with `Input/output error`.

sshfs outputs:

```
$ sshfs -p 7292 server:/in/vm/dir ~/vm_dir -d
FUSE library version: 2.9.2
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
unique: 1, opcode: INIT (26), nodeid: 0, insize: 56, pid: 0
INIT: 7.20
flags=0x000017fb
max_readahead=0x00020000
   INIT: 7.19
   flags=0x00000011
   max_readahead=0x00020000
   max_write=0x00020000
   max_background=0
   congestion_threshold=0
   unique: 1, success, outsize: 40
unique: 2, opcode: GETATTR (3), nodeid: 1, insize: 56, pid: 2287
getattr /
unique: 3, opcode: OPENDIR (27), nodeid: 1, insize: 48, pid: 21063
   unique: 3, success, outsize: 32
unique: 4, opcode: LOOKUP (1), nodeid: 1, insize: 57, pid: 2288
LOOKUP /.xdg-volume-info
getattr /.xdg-volume-info
   unique: 2, success, outsize: 120
   unique: 4, error: -2 (No such file or directory), outsize: 16
unique: 5, opcode: RELEASEDIR (29), nodeid: 1, insize: 64, pid: 0
   unique: 5, success, outsize: 16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
error: -2 (No such file or directory)
```

indicates that the remote directory is not present. Check that `/in/vm/dir` is present, and is not a symlink. If it is a symlink, you **must** include the trailing slash, as in `/in/vm/dir/`.